# Creating my custom tooltip using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jquery plugin with mouse hide and show I am trying to create tool tip.I am facing two problem

1. Whether my code is correct for `mouseout` and `mouseleave`
2. When I am creating lot of tooltip it was not positioning correctly it was coming down actually it has to come to right side.

I have found so many from stack Overflow but nothing is working out.

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tooltip").hide();
            $("#help").on({

                mouseenter: function () {
                    $("#showtooltip").show();
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $("#showtooltip").hide();
                }
            });
            $("#help1").on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $("#showtooltip1").show();
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $("#showtooltip1").hide();
                }
            });
            $("#help2").on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $("#showtooltip2").show();
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $("#showtooltip2").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Third mouse over was not working. I am trying to creating I think missed something.

Here is the jsbin [Link](http://jsbin.com/yexawi/edit?html,js,output)

Kindly help me

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css rules to your `.tooltip` class:

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;  /* define how much space from tooltip to the top
```

and this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".tooltip").hide();
                $("#help").on({

                    mouseenter: function (e) {
                        $("#showtooltip").show();
                        $("#showtooltip").css('left', e.pageX); // added

                    },
                    mouseleave: function () {
                        $("#showtooltip").hide();
                    }
                });
                $("#help1").on({
                    mouseenter: function (e) {
                        $("#showtooltip1").show();
                      $("#showtooltip1").css('left', e.pageX); // added
                    },
                    mouseleave: function () {
                        $("#showtooltip1").hide();
                    }
                });
                $("#help2").on({
                    mouseenter: function (e) {
                        $("#showtooltip2").show();
                        $("#showtooltip2").css('left', e.pageX); // added

                    },
                    mouseleave: function () {
                        $("#showtooltip2").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

I added only this line in javascript `mouseenter` function:

```
$("#showtooltip").css('left', e.pageX);
```

It sets the tooltip left coordinate, in case you have many items, the tooltip will show exactly beneath the hovered item.

**Customization**

If you want the tooltip right of the hovered item, you will need to add this css:

```
var rightMargin = 20; // or whatever fits your needs
$("#showtooltip").css('left', e.pageX + rightMargin);
```

and change your css `top` property above.

**Update**
Since this code of yours is very coupled and you asked for a better solution, here it is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".tooltip").hide();
                $(".help").on({

                    mouseenter: function (e) {
                        var tooltip = $(this).next();                                            tooltip.show();
                        tooltip.css('left', e.pageX + 20);

                    },
                    mouseleave: function () {
                        $(this).next().hide();
                    }
                });

            });
```

to work this, you gonna have to remove your coupled ids and instead add to every anchor tag class `help`.

the code simply checks if the user is hovering a link, and if so, then just show the next element after it, which happens to be the tooltip.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/gacosevaza/edit?html,js,output)

Cheers

Comment: @1I13v is this the correct way or can we do in a better way my third tooltip was not working kindly please helpe me

Comment: thanks 1I13v whether my coding is correct can we do any alterations for this because i will if i have 30 tooltips code will go long how to reduce this

Comment: thanks for helping but with the new code it was not working for all the three tooltip :(

Comment: I put a fiddle to try it